# Python urllib2. URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted>

Tags: python, urllib2

I'm making multiple connection to API. Making delete query. I got that error on a 3000'th query.

Something like this:

```
 def delete_request(self,path):
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPHandler)
    request = urllib2.Request('%s%s'%(self.endpoint,path))
    signature = self._gen_auth('DELETE', path, '')
    request.add_header('X-COMPANY-SIGNATURE-AUTH', signature)
    request.get_method = lambda: 'DELETE'
    resp = opener.open(request)
```

Than in console:

```
for i in xrange(300000): 
    con.delete_request('/integration/sitemap/item.xml/media/%d/' % i)
```

After about 3000'th request it says:

```
URLError: urlopen error [Errno 10048]
Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port)
is normally permitted
```

Comment: Where is the endpoint definition?

Comment: I show only one method of Connection class. Endpoint is http://localhost:8000

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error comes from Windows itself, see [Avoiding TCP/IP Port Exhaustion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560610%28v=bts.20%29.aspx). To fix the error close your connection, you are not calling opener.close() hence leaking sockets.

Comment: Thanks. That save me a lot of time.