# problem: Socket error [Address already in use] in python/selenium

Tags: python, selenium-rc, socketexception

I have a troublesome problem **socket.error error: [Errno 10048]: Address already in use. Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/IP address/port) is normally permitted** during automated tests using Selenium with Python. The problem is so interesting that it runs on one machine (Linux) works correctly, but on another machine (WindowsXP) generates this error.
I would add that the problem arose after the reinstallation of the system and set up all over again - with the previous configuration everything worked properly.
Is there maybe something I forgot? Has anyone come up with such a problem before?

Does anyone have an idea of ​​how to deal with this problem?

**The current configuration / libraries:**

python 2.7, numpy, selenium.py

Comment: Selenium runs on port 4444 by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in the post below:

[Python urllib2. URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526933/python-urllib2-urlerror-urlopen-error-errno-10048-only-one-usage-of-each-soc)

It turned out that this problem is limitation of Windows

Answer (score 1):

If you open/close the socket multiple times, it could be in the TIME_WAIT state. This would explain why it acts differently on separate platforms (different TIME_WAIT settings and TCP stack). If you're controlling the socket object, you can set SO_REUSEADDR before binding to fix the problem.

For example:

```
sock = socket.socket()
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, server.getsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR) | 1)
```

You can run `netstat -b` from the command prompt to give you a list of open sockets with the state and owning process.

Answer (score 0):

There are several possibilities. If none of your tests can listen on some port (you don't say what port) then perhaps your Windows machine is running something on a port that you previously had open; this new service may have appeared during the reinstall. If, on the other hand, it's only a problem for some tests, or it's a little sporadic, then it may be either a programming issue (forgetting to close a socket in an early test which interferes with a later one) or a timing issue  (the earlier test's socket isn't quite through closing before the new one tries to open up). Obviously there are different ways to address each of these problems, but I don't think we can help more than this without more details.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a software on your Windows that already use port 4444, can you try set Selenium to another port and try again?