# Socket error in python server code

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a python server script given below

```
# create the server, binding to localhost on port 9999
#
server = SocketServer.TCPServer((options.ip, options.port), cmdHandler)

While running a Python server script I am getting the following error:

File "C:\Devcon\OCDServer_New.py", line 225, in runTest
server = SocketServer.TCPServer((options.ip, options.port), cmdHandler)
File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 419, in __init__
self.server_bind()
File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 430, in server_bind
self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 224, in meth
return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
**socket.error: [Errno 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted**
```

How to solve this? In one link I found socket shutdown is a solution. But here the issue is coming while creating the socket itself. It might be because it was opened previously and not closed correctly. But I am unable to reset the entire thing and run the script again. Got stuck here.

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3? Also, dupe of my question from 10 minutes ago [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28234188/reuse-of-sockets)!

Comment: Its python 2.7 in the server and python 3 running on my machine...I checked the link...it says its in time_wait state...how to kill it ?

Comment: Make sure you close the socket. Temporarily, you might be able to make it work using a different port.

Comment: Instead of changing the port number everytime, I thought of trying this: SocketServer.TCPServer.allow_reuse_address = True. But, got the error: socket.error: [Errno 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Comment: Please provide more code.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a different port to see if you get the same message or a different one. Something else could be using the same port therefore your code not being able to use it.

Comment: Instead of changing the port number everytime, I thought of trying this: SocketServer.TCPServer.allow_reuse_address = True. But, got the error: socket.error: [Errno 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Comment: You don't need to change the port everytime just to some other port. If you get the same error then something in your code is the issue if not then it was some other program using the port. With that error I'd say you don't have the access rights to perform that action. Since I don't know your set up I'm not sure how I can help you. But try run your code as an Admin if possible.